# Spotify Randomize Playlist Button

Tags: spotify, shuffle

With all of the Spotify randomization questions and related updates, this seems like a super overdone and already dealt with issue.  The problem however, is that I believe that the great devs over at Spotify have answered the wrong question.  From what I read on their site, they seem to think that the problem with the random is that the same artist is played multiple times in a row, while the actual issue, is that a small portion of the songs seem to have a priority over others and are played many more times than the others.

The issue, is that when I have a playlist with 500 or so songs in it, the same 50 play over and over again, and if I throw in a one off artist in there, they are never heard.  A good 95% of my listening time with Spotify has been the same 50 songs.  I have read through their blog posts about their shuffle feature and believe there might be an issue with certain songs receiving more of a priority over others.

A great and simple solution to this problem would be to add a "Randomize Playlist" button that would allow for the user to put the playlist in a non-sorted random order, possibly having it as an option in the bar where you can sort according to Artist name, Song name, and Date.  This would allow for a user to randomize the playlist whenever they like, and guarantee, that when played through, there would be no favorites and that each song in the playlist would be played once.

A possible implementation could be similar to what the guys over at TextMechanic did with their text sorting tool that can be found here:

http://textmechanic.com/text-tools/basic-text-tools/sort-text-lines/

I really think that this feature would be a welcome addition to Spotify, and it would solve many users annoyance with the apparent favoritism to a list of songs while using the shuffle play feature.  I love music, and I really love the Spotify app, and as such, I listen to many, many hours of music a week.  This small feature would fix one of my only gripes with the software and would greatly improve my experience.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really have an answer as this isn't really a question, i think its best to write this note to spotify as it isn't a question relevant to stack overflow

Comment: On their dev support page, they said to make a post on here and tag it with spotify to get them to read it.

Comment: Wow seriously? That has got to be one of the worst customer support protocols imaginable.